# Issue Setting the Required flag on my Select list with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a Select list that I'm loading from a datastore,  I am adding a placeholder of Please select. but angularjs keeps setting the selected flag on this.   I have also tried removing the Please Select option entirely but, angular adds an empty select item and selects it also.  any thoughts?  Heres the code for the select list.

```
<select ng-model="vm.SelectedContainerDefinition" 
  id="Name" name="ContainerName" 
  class="form-control" 
  ng-options="Container.Name  for Container in ContainerDefinitions" 
  ng-selected="false" required>
    <option  value="" >please select</option>
</select> 
<span ng-show="form.ContainerName.$dirty && form.ContainerName.$error.required" 
  class="help-block">
    Container Name required
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.   when I was Initializing the model, I was also creating an instance of the selected item. So in this case I had

```
vm.SelectedContainerDefinition = {};
```

I simply removed this line and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="display:none"` to your option element and it will work like a charm:

```
<select ng-model="vm.SelectedContainerDefinition" id="Name" name="ContainerName" class="form-control"
                                        ng-options="Container.Name  for Container in ContainerDefinitions" ng-selected="false" required>
                                    <option style="display:none" value="">select a type</option>         
                                </select>
```

Comment: it still sets the Selected = "selected".  I'm trying to use the Required validation and its getting in the way. here's the source after adding display = "none" <option value="" style="display:none" class="" selected="selected">please select</option>

Comment: Do you want to select some 'real' value instead of "select a type" or prevent from selection any value at first and trigger validation if user not choose any?

Comment: veg, I would like the Options to say Select a type, on Init,  but have the required validation to prevent a post if the user does not select a "real" value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the `disabled` attribute.

```
<select ng-model="vm.SelectedContainerDefinition" id="Name" name="ContainerName" class="form-control" ng-options="Container.Name  for Container in ContainerDefinitions" ng-selected="false" required>
  <option  value="" disabled>please select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: disabled doesn't do it. It still allows the form to pass validation because it sets the selected ="selected" on the Please Select Option when the control intializes. .

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for your model:

```
vm.SelectedContainerDefinition = ContainerDefinitions[0]
```

It should show the first item as selected.

Comment: That just Automatically selects the first Item in the Array which isn't what I need. I need the user to see "Select a Type" and then prevent a post until the user selects a real value.